# (double)Math.round(dblPerimeter * 100) / 100); why is it times 100 then divide by 100?

Tags: java

I want to know why is that code times perimeter 100 then divide it by 100?

```
(double)Math.round(dblPerimeter * 100) / 100);
```

Comment: Do you know what `Math.round()` does?

Comment: Aside: `dblPerimeter` is not a very good name. This is the "Systems Hungarian" form of Hungarian notation, and is generally frowned upon.

Comment: If the intention is, as it would appear, to round it to two decimal places, `double` is a poor choice of type. `BigDecimal` would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code would round `dblPerimeter` to 2 decimal places.

Example on how this works:

Let `dblPerimeter = 123.456`. Round `dblPerimeter` to 2 decimals

1. multiply by 100: 123.456 * 100 = 12345.6
2. `Math.round()` 12345.6 to 12346
3. cast 12346 to `(double)`: 12346.0
4. divide by 100: 12346.0 / 100 = 123.46

Comment: `Math.round()` returns a `double`, so the cast is unnecessary.

Comment: @KenY-N The return type [in the javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-) is listed as `long`.

Answer (score 0):

Rounding to the second decimal place. Eventhough you can never be exactly sure with floating-point-arithmetics, but this is what it is supposed to do.